# Spark: Spark UI not reflecting the right executor count

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We are running a spark streaming application where we want to increase the number of executors spark uses ....so updated **spark-default.conf** increasing **spark.executor.instances** from **28** to **40** but the change is not reflected in the UI

```
1 Master/Driver Node : 
  Memory :24GB Cores :8 

4 Worker Nodes : 
  Memory :24GB Cores :8

spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled     true
spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown true
spark.executor.instances                 28
spark.executor.memory                    2560MB
spark.executor.cores                     4
spark.driver.memory                      3G
spark.driver.cores                       1
```

[image: Spark UI not reflecting the right executor count]

**Note** : restarted spark start-master.sh and start-slaves.sh but no change .Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated. this is the **yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>hdfs-name-node</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>22528</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>7</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>22528</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>file:///tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir,file:///tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir/filecache,file:///tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir/usercache</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms</name>
        <value>500</value>
    </property>

    <property>
         <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb</name>
         <value>512</value>
    </property>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Did you try setting this from within the code like:
`val conf = new SparkConf(); conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "40");val sparkSession = SparkSession.config(conf).getOrCreate();`

Comment: Executer instances are depends on available CPU cores in cluster. How many free cores available in your cluster ?

Comment: What is overall resource on your cluster cores and RAM ?

Comment: @mrsrinivas Added the cluster info to the question please take a look

Comment: @FaigB Added the overal resource on cluster to the question please take a look

Comment: From resources in case mapping physical cores for executors the count would be 9 but the image shows running 20 executors  and it means you are running on Yarn with vCores mapped to physical core. Please check from resource manager how many vCores overall you have ?

Comment: @FaigB you are absolutely right ! we are using yarn ...i have updated the question with the yarn-site.xml ...which has 7 vcores .( 1 core left for os on node and 2GB left for os as well) please take a look

Comment: check from Spark web UI what config was provided for executors

Answer (score 0):

The yarn-site config allocates 7 cores per each node so overall you have 35 cores which means at most you can run 34 executors with 1 core (1 core for driver).

Comment: out of the 5 nodes we have one is master node and rest 4 nodes are workers (4*7 = 28) ?..so can we take into consideration master cores ...i thought no work get's done on the master ..and only workers do the work ..that makes the number of cores which we can use to only 28 ? please correct me if i'm wrong in my assumption

Comment: deployment on yarn cluster resource control managed by yarn and if the mentioned node included in cluster so its' resources also will be shared.